# React Native Application Adding Multiple Core-Pods on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I am not very familiar with the iOS development and I request your help.

My react-native application in iOS has stopped Archiving after two React-Core dependencies appeared in the Pod list. I am able to **Build** without any problems.

[image: Duplicate Pods]

And the Error-Message:

[image: Error]

1. I already tried cleaning XCode derived-data, npm-cache, rebuilt npm-folder and Pods.
2. I also tried to fix dependencies using `npm audit fix` but there are no conflicting dependencies in the project.
3. I removed this Pod (React-Core-60309c9c) and re-tried but got this message instead.

```
ld: library not found for -lReact-Core-60309c9c
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

4. I am using the workspace to compile (instead of the project file).
5. As is necessary - I remove both the "AccessibilityResource" packages before I compile.

The package.json has the following:

```
    "@notifee/react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "i18next": "^21.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.14.3",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "realm": "^10.10.1"
  }
```

I am not even sure what other information I can share that might be relevant.

Please help identifying what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: No @kEpEx. I am modifying the files manually every time I have to make changes to the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your `podfile` configuration, so I can't pinpoint the exact one but can you kindly look into this discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29709)? Some workarounds mentioned here should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Bhishak. My problem is not with removal of Accessibility Resources but that there are two of these libraries referred. Removing them manually does not automatically clean up the compile scripts that are automatically created by RN.

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for us was:

To remove a redundant pod install in our `Podfile`, podfile by default installs all pods from your `package.json` and `node_modules` so having a manual pod install duplicates stuff in our Pod xcode project

Example:

```
target 'MyApp' do

  pod 'RNPermissions' <-- remove this line, (it could be any library)

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
   ...
```